# Preventing integrity constraint violation while replacing array collection items with new ones in 1-N association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony application, if I get rid of first `$em->flush();` I'll get an `integrity constraint violation on "car.code"` error because `AAA` is still in DB. If this was a batch process where there were 10 persons, I would need to `flush` 20 times which is not a good idea. So the question is, is there a way of reducing `flush` to **1** call right at the end? I mean existing records somehow will be removed before sticking new ones in with a single `flush`.

**CURRENT LOGIC**

```
// Find the "person" object
$person = .....;

// Remove all existing "car" objects
$person->getCars()->clear();
$em->flush();

// Create new "car" objects
foreach ($request as $data) {
    $car = new Car;
    $car->setCode($data->code);
    // ......
}
$em->flush();
```

**REQUEST**

```
PUT persons/10/cars.json
{
  [
    {
      "code": "AAA",
      "status": "ByeA"
    },
    {
      "code": "EEE",
      "status": "ByeE"
    }
  ]
}
```

**CURRENT DATA IN DATABASE**

```
SELECT * FROM person;
id
--
10

SELECT * FROM car;
id  code  status  person_id
--  ----  ------  ---------
1   AAA   HelloA  10
2   BBB   HelloB  10
3   CCC   HelloC  10
4   DDD   HelloD  10
```

**AFTER PROCESSING THE REQUEST**

```
SELECT * FROM person;
id
--
10

SELECT * FROM car;
id  code  status  person_id
--  ----  ------  ---------
5   AAA   ByeA    10
6   EEE   ByeE    10
```

**1 to N ENTITY STRUCTURE**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Person
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="person",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true
     *     )
     */
    private $cars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //....
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"code"})})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Car
{
    private $id;

    private $code;

    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $person;

    //....
}
```

Comment: What about a "cars" setter on the `Person` entity ? such as `setCars($cars) { $this->cars = new ArrayCollection(); foreach ($cars as $car) {$this->cars->add($car); ......` Personally, I initialize a new ArrayCollection when I want to clear an existing collection

Comment: @ceadreak I'm sorry but I don't know what has your comment got to do with the question!

Comment: Please, see my answer, and sorry if this is not what you expect !

Answer (score 0):

What about this logic ?

```
// Find the "person" object
$person = .....;
$cars   = [];

// Create new "car" objects
foreach ($request as $data) {
    $car = new Car;
    $car->setCode($data->code);
    // ......

    $cars[] = $car;
}

$person->setCars($cars);    

$em->persist();
$em->flush();
```

In the `Car` entity

```
public function setPerson(Person $person)
{
     $this->person = $person;

     return $this;
}
```

In the `Person` entity

```
public function setCars($cars)
{
    $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();

    return $this->addCars($cars);
}

public function addCars($cars)
{
    foreach ($cars as $car)
    {
        $this->addCar($car);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function addCar(Car $car)
{
    if (!$this->cars->contains($car)
    {
        $this->cars->add($car);
        $car->setPerson($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't understand the question.

Comment: Or maybe the question isn't really clear :) in the code above, you have only one flush call at the end and it works with batch processing. So what more could you ask for ?